# ckeditor error when change http to https website

Tags: javascript, laravel, ckeditor

when I open dev tools It show

Mixed Content: The page at 'PATH' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'PATH/ckeditor.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

How can i fix this

Comment: add proper path to this file PATH/ckeditor.js like HTTPS://BlAH/BLAH/ckeditor.js
In short for secure domain you need to add path of the secure domain(css,js)

Comment: @DsRaj Thank you It's work coz I use laravel {{ asset('path')}} I change it to real path ckeditor

Comment: Okay I am going to add this as an answer so it will other user too

Comment: =] i'll mark thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the proper path to this file PATH/ckeditor.js like `HTTPS://DOMAIN/ckeditor.js`

In short for the secure domain you need to add the path of the secure domain(CSS, js), so everytime before you switch to HTTPS, you'll need to update all of the internal links in your website.